# Lifecycle of npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

Npm install executes certain scripts like `preinstall` , `postinstall` and others.

I couldn't find explicit list and ordering of these scripts. It would be great to get some clarification  and detailed overview of this process.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is described on the NPM page: [npm-scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts).
It is a bit cryptic, but the logic is straightforward.

E.g. running 
`npm install` will do `preinstall install postinstall prepublish` - this is rather exceptional case, prepublish only runs if there are no arguments, i.e. run locally. Also check which version of npm you are running, as `prepublish` with local `install` has been deprecated in 4.x in favour of another approach, described in [issue 10074](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10074) and has a nice explanation in this [blog](https://iamakulov.com/notes/all/npm-4-prepublish/). It comes down to the fact that `npm install` without arguments runs when you clone a package and it makes sense to prepare it. But people dislike this behaviour, so it was decided to split prepublish into two stages. `prepare` runs instead of `prepublish` during publishing and local `npm install`. `prepublishOnly` runs only with `npm publish`.

Hence 
`npm publish` will do `prepublish publish postpublish` or `prepare prepublishOnly publish postpublish` on 4.x

Finally, with version 6.x, `npm install` runs `preinstall install postinstall prepare` while `npm publish` runs `prepare prepublish publish postpublish`.

As far as I know, all other commands follow the logic of `preX`, `X`, `postX`.

Comment: What happens if you do `npm install acme`?  Does it run `preinstall install postinstall prepare`?  Does it run those scripts from `acme` or from the local package?

Comment: Why does `prepare` run at the end of install, but run at the beginning of `publish`? This seems quite strange, in that if I create a command to run before I need to publish, it is also the last command to run during installation.... how does this make sense?